# Laravel hasFile() return true even if file is not uploaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-request

If I uploaded the file works all perfectly, but when I avoid to upload it ( is optional ) I get this error:

```
fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory
```

In my controller I tried to check if file exists with the function hasFile but it seems doesn't work:

```
 if($request->hasFile('my_file')) {
          $fileName = time().'.'.$request->my_file->extension();
          $request->my_file->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileName);
          $content->my_file= $fileName;
        }
```

Also I tried to print the content of $request->my_file to debug with dd($request->my_file). It's null.

The stranger thing is that also if $request->my_file is null this check getting the error:

```
if($request->file('my_file') != null)
```

Comment: Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: I already checked and yes, I added enctype="multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 1):

I found and solved the problem.
HasFile works correctly but the error was in a next step of saving.